# ActiveRecord with() where()

Tags: yii2

Скажите, если делать запрос с with, но нужно в where указать параметры для полей из разных таблиц, то как это сделать? Например, есть три связанные таблицы test, test2 и test3. Нужно получить записи из всех таблиц с условиям по test2 (поле col=5) и test3( new_col=2). Как это прописать?

```
$test=Test::found()->with('test2.test3')->where()->asArray->all();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого стоит использовать

```
->joinWith(['test2', 'test2.test3'])
```

тогда можно будет использовать

```
->where(['test2.col' => 5, 'test3.new_col' => 2])
```

[Документация](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#joining-with-relations) и [Статья на тему](https://habrahabr.ru/post/306248/)

[Схожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606740/use-joins-for-multiple-tables-in-yii2)